# In C#, what is the best way to determine if a decimal "is an int"?

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a variable that is a decimal and i want to determine if it "is an int"

```
  public bool IsanInt(decimal variable)
```

so if the variable passed in was 1, i want to return true
if it was 1.5, it would return  false
.5 would be false
10 would be true

what is the best way to do this check?

Comment: `variable == (int)variable`?

Comment: What about 2^32 - is it "int" or not for your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsInt(3.0m)); // True
        Console.WriteLine(IsInt(3.1m)); // False
    }

    public static bool IsInt(decimal variable)
    {
        return ((variable % 1) == 0);
    }
}
```

Basically, that method is all you need.  I just included the entire console program so that you can see the results.

**EDIT:**

So, after some brainstorming on the comments below, I found that it's incredibly difficult, if not impossible (I haven't found the way) to find if the value is `decimal` or "`integer`" if the decimal value being provided at its very high value.  Decimal holds a higher value than even `UInt64`.  When you run this line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Decimal.MaxValue - 0.5m);
```

Output:

```
79228162514264337593543950334
```

... you will see that it won't print the decimal value after the period.  There is a maximum limitation that is forcing the truncation, so you'll never see that 0.5 being part of the that large value.  My method can't fix that limitation.  I'm not sure if there's anything that can do that within C# or .NET, but I'm all ears.

There's a good article on what you can and can't do with `decimal`... better than what MSDN provides in my opinion:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/decimal

Comment: +0: `(Decimal.MaxValue-0.5m) % 1` ? To be complete your answer should specify when your method is applicable.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Perhaps... but I'm not sure when anyone would calculate anything with a figure such as 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,334.5.  It's always a possibility, of course.  Until you mentioned it, I didn't know of this restriction on my method.  Care to share why this occurs?

Comment: (Decimal.MaxValue-0.5m) % 1m returns 0 here, not sure what's your point?

Comment: @Asik same as  `Decimal.MaxValue % 1` - clearly both `x` and `x+0.5` should not have remainder 0.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It seems to be an interesting limitation for my answer and for Asik's answer... I've tested both of them.  Do you know why this is occurring?

Comment: @B.K.: You can work out the answer to your question by answering these two questions: How many significant digits do you need to represent `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,334.5`? How many significant digits can be stored in a decimal?

Comment: @EricLippert Yep, I just figured it out right when I saw your comment and posted an edit.  It's a shame on my part, since I took an Assembly class in college.

Comment: +1... @EricLippert shame on me that I actually though it did not work for totally different reason (somehow I thought there is no `decimal%decimal` and it would cast `decimal` down to something like `long` - which is would cause compile error)... shame... thanks all for entertaining question and good learning.

Comment: Yes, as it turns out, Decimal.MaxValue - 0.5M == Decimal.MaxValue - 1M, due to limited precision.

Answer (score 3):

```
public bool IsInteger(decimal value)
{
    return value == Math.Round(value);
}
```

Comment: `IsAnInt(Decimal.MaxValue)`. Hmmm.

Comment: Works for me, what's your concern?

Comment: Well, I guess it hinges, as Alexei asks above, on what leora considers an int. Is it an Int32 or Int64? If so, your code doesn't produce the desired result. Is it the mathematical concept of an integer? Then it'll work.

Comment: +1. Consider renaming the method so it is clear that "Int" has nothing to do with `int` but rather means "whole number". I would personally use [Math.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it more clearly matches to description of the behavior (also both endup with the same result in this case).

Comment: Oh I see. From the examples given in the question I think it's clear the method should return whether there is a fractional part.

Answer (score 2):

how about something like

```
return Math.Round(n) == n
```